# Compound check for file contents in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a compound if-statement using the new-test in Bash.  I want to check that a file exists and that two other files have particular contents.  My grep searches don't seem to work as well when nested within a test.

```
echo "a" >> file_a
echo "b" >> file_b 
echo "c" >> file_c
if [[ -f file_a && \
  $(grep -q "b" file_b) && \
  $(grep -q "c" file_c) ]]; then
  echo "Got 'em"
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When testing the exit status of a command (e.g. `grep`), you don't need or want `[[ ]]` or `$( )` or any of that stuff. `if` checks the exit status of whatever's between `if` and `then`, and takes the appropriate branch based on whether it succeeded or failed.

`$( )` exists to capture the output of a command (i.e. what it prints as it runs -- `grep -q` does not print anything), and use it as part of another command. That's not what you want at all.

`[[ ]]` evaluates a test expression (which can test whether e.g. a file exists, whether two strings are equal, etc), and converts the result into an exit status. But with `grep -q` it's already producing an exit status, so you don't need some sort of test to get it into that form.

You *do* need `[[ ]]` to check whether file_a exists, but that's the only role it'll play here. And you need `&&` to make a compound command that succeeds only if all parts of it succeed. So what you want is:

```
...
if [[ -f file_a  ]] && 
  grep -q "b" file_b &&
  grep -q "c" file_c; then
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `-q` from grep and test if the expression inside the Command Substitution is not empty using the `-n` flag.

```
if [[ -f file_a && -n $(grep "b" file_b) && -n $(grep "c" file_c)  ]]; then
  echo "Got 'em"
fi
```

- Although the `-n` can be omitted, which will work as if you have the `-n` flag inside the test.
- Generally the `if` clause and the `[[` or `[`  is not needed if you're just going to test for a pattern match using grep.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, get rid of the "if" entirely:

```
test -f file_a && grep -q "b" file_b && grep -q "c" file_c && echo "Got em"
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` has exit code 0 on success, but the `test` wants a truthy value.  You have to invert the exit code of grep or check that it exited with 0:

```
if [[ -f file_a && \
      ! $(grep -q "b" file_b) && \
      ! $(grep -q "c" file_c) ]]; then
  echo "Got 'em"
fi
```

or

```
if [[ -f file_a && \
      $(grep -q "b" file_b) -eq 0 && \
      $(grep -q "c" file_c) -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Got 'em"
fi
```

Ideally there's a more readable way than putting it into a subshell with `$()`.

Comment: That doesn't work; `$(cmd)` returns _stdout_ not _exit status_. Plus as Jetchisel notes, `[[` (like `[`, and `test` is actually `[` not `[[`) defaults to string-nonempty not arith-nonzero. You can do `$(grep -q b file_b; echo $?) -eq -0` -- or using a more useful output `$(grep -c b file_b)  -gt 0`. Oh and `[[ .. ]]` is shell syntax so you don't need to backslash the newlines.